# count of row by row from another table holding some conditions on both tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

There are two tables Table1 and Table2

```
A B C  S
a 1 21 Summer
b 2 22 Summer
c 3 34 Summer

D E F  S
a 1 21 Summer
d 5 22 Summer
f 2 34 Summer
```

I wanted to fetch all columns of Table first and count of column F from table second based on conditions such as column B OF table first is less than values of column E of table second.

I tried this query

```
select a.*,
      (select count(F) from Table2 JOIN Table1 on table1.S=table2.S where table1.B<table2.E ) AS Cnt
from Table1 a
```

However it is giving me same count for all rows which is incorrect
I need count based on condition fulfilled.

Comment: Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (A Varchar(10), B INT, C INT,  S  Varchar(10))
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (D Varchar(10), E INT, F INT,  S  Varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES
('a', 1, 21,'Summer'),
('b', 2 ,22,'Summer'),
('c', 3, 34,'Summer')
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES
 
('a', 1, 21,'Summer'),
('d', 5 ,22,'Summer'),
('f', 2 ,34,'Summer')


  SELECT
    T1.A,T1.B,T1.C,T1.S,
    COUNT(T2.S) as Counts
FROM @T1 T1
  left JOIN @T2 T2
  ON T1.S = T2.S AND T1.B < T2.E
GROUP BY T1.A,T1.B,T1.C,T1.S
```

Output

```
A   B   C   S   Counts
a   1   21  Summer  2
b   2   22  Summer  1
c   3   34  Summer  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
      (select count(t2.F)
       from Table2 t2 
       where a.S = t2.S and t1.B < t2.E
      ) as Cnt
from Table1 a
```

Comment: correlated subquery is not working do you know any other solution

Comment: Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
    select *,
  (select count(F)
   from T2
   where T1.S = T2.S AND T1.B < T2.E
  ) as Cnt  from T1
```

Comment: Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate